# How to install just XLA?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, jax, tensorflow-xla

I want to use XLA as a backend for my project. Is there a recommended way to install it on its own (without the rest of TensorFlow). Jax probably does this, but looking in their repository it's not obvious how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XLA has been moved to the [OpenXLA GitHub organization](https://github.com/openxla/xla). It can be installed on its own from there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way to install XLA on its own apart from tensorflow.

That said, JAX does extract, build, and bundle XLA separately from tensorflow within the [jaxlib](https://pypi.org/project/jaxlib/) package. You can see the relevant build scripts for jaxlib on various platforms here: https://github.com/google/jax/tree/main/build

In particular, take a look at [build_wheel.py](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/main/build/build_wheel.py), which contains the scripts that extract relevant pieces of XLA from the tensorflow source as part of the jaxlib build.

Comment: thanks. That's quite a build script. For now I've raised [a ticket](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/50681) with TensorFlow to have XLA available on its own

Comment: ah, i see - do you mean jaxlib essentially _is_ a standalone XLA? or is a Python wrapped XLA? I guess the later since it's pip installable. I'm looking for a C/C++ API ideally

Comment: Not exactly - jaxlib is not designed as a general-purpose build of XLA. That said it is possible to interface with the XLA API via C++ to some extent: see, for example https://dfm.io/posts/extending-jax/

Answer (score 0):

The [elixir-nx](https://github.com/elixir-nx) project has released [XLA binaries](https://github.com/elixir-nx/xla).

The XLA interface is in `tensorflow/compiler/xla`. The rest, IIUC, is supporting functionality.